# How to call a java class method from javascript

Tags: javascript, java, applet, java-web-start

I'd an applet "edu.MGT.MainApplet" implemented in a jar "MGT2-0.0.1.jar". A local html page used the tag `<applet>` to call methods of this class. Everything was working correctly some time ago.

(In detail: the applet provides a set of methods for analysis and transformation of mathematical expression. Mathematical expressions are stored as data trees, and the set of methods allows apply to them usual math operations, finding sub-expressions, execute calculus, ... . The API of the applet is very simple: methods have a name and simple arguments, usually only one integer or one string and returns one string. The trees with the math expressions are never transferred, they are keep at applet. The html/javascript GUI contains buttons to execute the methods and transforms the string result, using MathJax, to graphical mathematical expressions).

The related javascript lines are:

```
> <applet id="mgt"
>         archive="MGT2-0.0.1.jar"  style="width: 1px; height: 1px; float: left;"
>         code="edu.MGT.MainApplet"> 
> </applet>
> 
> <script>
>     var TeX = mgt.predefined(1);
> ...
```

where "mgt.predefined(1)" is one example of a call to one method of the java class that is the applet.

Nowadays, with navigator firefox 57.0, the console shows the error:

> TypeError: mgt.predefined is not a function [Learn More]
>   gtexpression1.html:90:15

I've checked the content of the jar. Class exists and method exists:

```
$ jar -xvf MGT2-0.0.1.jar 
...
 inflated: edu/MGT/MainApplet.class
...
```

and the class has the related method:

```
$ javap edu/MGT/MainApplet.class
Compiled from "MainApplet.java"
public class edu.MGT.MainApplet extends java.applet.Applet {
  ...
  public java.lang.String predefined(int);
```

After lots of hours googling and trying ...

**Try number 1:**

use `<object>` instead of `<applet>`: no changes in the result.

**Try number 2:**

Move to Java Web Start. I've wrote following MGT2.jnlp file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
        <information>
            <title>MGT</title>
            <vendor>private</vendor>
        </information>

        <resources>
            <j2se version="1.7+"
                href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
            <jar href="MGT2-0.0.1.jar" main="true" />
        </resources>

    <applet-desc main-class="edu.MGT.MainApplet"
             name="MGT" 
             width="1" height="1">
    </applet-desc>

        <update check="background"/>
    </jnlp>
```

and changed the javascript part to:

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

<script>
    var attributes = {
           code: "edu.MGT.MainApplet", 
           id: "MGT",
           width:1, height:1} ; 
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'MGT2.jnlp'} ; 
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
```

but following error appears:

> ReferenceError: mgt is not defined [Learn More]
>   gtexpression1.html:103:9

**Try number 3:**

Same jnlp file than in previous, one more line in the javascript code:

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

<script>
    var attributes = {
           code: "edu.MGT.MainApplet", 
           id: "mgt",
           width:1, height:1} ; 
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'MGT2.jnlp'} ; 
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7'); 
    var mgt = document.getElementById("MGT");
```

and the error is:

> TypeError: mgt is null [Learn More] gtexpression1.html:103:9

Nowadays, how to call Java code from www page ?

Comment: when i saw the javascript tag i taught it some kind of es2020 syntax but then i realised it was java and not javascript

Comment: What does the applet do? It is likely, as mentioned in the answer, that whatever it does can be done using JS.

Comment: Hi @AndrewThompson. Thanks for your interest in the issue. I've added to the question  a new paragraph (see second paragraph of the question) with a more detailed description of the GUI, applet and API.

Comment: You're updating your question quite a lot, so that's good, but the updates seem incomplete: modern browsers don't run java on their own anymore, so do you have a java execution plugin installed that can kick in when the mime-type or object type is java related? Because without that, *nothing* will happen, no matter how many different approaches you use.

Comment: Hi @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: yes, a few obsessive with correct my poor English :-). What you say can be the answer "nowadays it is not possible to call a java class from a javascript in a html page". Something suppressing because: a) Oracle "sells" that the alternative, without loss of functionality, is convert the applet class to a "java web start" and b) there are not easy alternatives. Convert a simple statement as "mgt.predefined(1)" to an http request and convert the java class to a HttpServlet and use a application server as jboss or tomcat is not an easy change and has a lot of drawbacks.

Comment: java webstart is really just a file that you download and run, with whatever java you have installed picking up on the jnlp file extension - without a java plugin installed you won't get the auto-java-starting functionality.

Answer (score 0):

the `<applet>` tag has been [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/applet) for several years now, and definitely does nothing in any recent version of Firefox. So the simplest answer here would be that if you really are using firefox (you say you're using a firefox user agent, so it's unclear whether you mean you're using firefox, or you've change the useragent string to claim your non-firefox browser is firefox), the applet is never loaded, so your JS is trying to call something that doesn't exist as a function, and that's not going to work.

At the very least, you want to try to load your code with [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) instead (and then you'll need to have an applet execution plugin installed, FF/Chrome no longer execute java themselves), but an even better suggestion would be to not use Java at all, as modern JS has obviated the need for Java integration into pages.

Comment: Would the down voter care to explain? 'Bad news' is sometimes the correct & optimal answer, as in this case.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Sorry, but answer suggest a way to nowhere (change applet to object) and most part of text is lost in useless thoughs about if I'm really using firefox, if "applet" tag is obsolete, ... . The most important part is only a a phrase lost in a parenthesis in final paragraph. Moreover, important part, alternatives, is only present in phrase "modern JS obviated the need for Java", without proof or examples.

Comment: What I expected of an answer: problem is in my code or is common to all code that calls java from javascript inside navigators? Is java web start the solution? The only solution is pass from direct calls to an interface based on messages? Etc

Comment: There's really no need for "proof" in 2018 when it comes to claims that modern JS can do what Java does; this is one of the reasons why java's been removed from browsers for a few years now. The "conversion" is really just "work to be done by you" that turns whatever UI you have implemented in Java in DOM+JS instead, and have the data exchange happen through REST calls (in modern JS, using the fetch API). Stackoverflow is not the place to write a full tutorial, and the web is full of "how do I X" tutorials already, so you are still expected to research this yourself.

Comment: if you have java installed, and you explicitly made it install java execution plugins, *and* you allowed those to run in your browser, then `<object>` should work, as should java webstart. However, if you go that route you are effectively building "not a webpage" that most people will not be able to run at all, given that java is considered a terrible security risk these days (for good reasons that plenty of websearch results can explain).